# Get extent error in for loop but not individiually

Tags: shapefile, r, masking, rasterstack

I am masking and cropping a rasterstack to a shapefile I made. I have done this previously with another shapefile, this is no problems. However, when I do this with this specific shapefile I get the following error

```
Error in compareRaster(x) : different extent
```

I don't fully understand this because I'm comparing a raster to a shapefile and not two rasters. In addition all rasters in the rasterstack have the same extent and I'm masking them to the same shapefile. Finally, I can do the first 8 or so rasters in the raster stack manually, but when I set my loop to the first item, I get the above error. Can someone tell me what is going on?

My code:

```
praccirc = stack()
for (i in 1:1){
  maskraster = raster::mask(pracstack[[i]], delcirc)
  maskraster = raster::crop(maskraster,delcirc)
  praccirc= stack(janpmdelhi,maskraster)
}
**Error in compareRaster(x) : different extent**

#This works for raster 1 of the raster stack
pracras1 = pracstack[[1]]
pracras1mask = raster::mask(pracras1, delcirc)
pracras1mask = raster::crop(pracras1mask, delcirc)

#additionally this for loop works with this shapefile
pracdel=stack()

for (i in 1:nlayers(pracstack)){
  maskraster = raster::mask(pracstack[[i]], delshp)
  maskraster = raster::crop(maskraster,delshp)
  pracdel= stack(janpmdelhi,maskraster)
}
```

The Datasets and shapefiles can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ru0RrAYiUpiHJf56JUKuqacOBKteiypF?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting so that the mask is performed on the cropped object `mask(crop(x, m), m)`

Comment: I still get the same error. I also just tried separating the crop and mask into different for loops and the crop for loop works, but the mask for loop fails